# Got error while pushing code in git repository

Tags: git, gitorious

While pushing code in repository i am getting error like

```
nbmacmini9:bmp-ios afsarunnisa$ git push origin master
fatal: protocol error: expected sha/ref, got '
----------------------------------------------
The git:// url is read-only. Please see http://scm.company.com/bmp/bmp-ios for the push url, if you're a committer.
```

and the remote origins are correct. How can i solve this ?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in this remote?

Comment: How can i check permissions ? I am able to clone this repository thats why i am thing that i have permissions. In Gitorious project dashboard , i am not member of this project

Comment: Ask your system administrator to check this and provide you permissions to work on the project

Comment: Please clarify what remote urls you are using, what is the result from `git remote -v`?

Comment: You may need to check what url that is used for origin, see http://geekdevs.com/2012/03/solved-the-git-protocol-is-read-only-when-doing-git-push-on-gitorious/

Answer (score 1):

Cloning just means you can see the repository. To be allowed to push, normally you need RSA key authentication. Your first error

> expected sha/ref, got '

looks like you haven't provided a key to the repo admin. Is this a project where you're supposed to have write permissions? Normally in open source or not-your-own projects, you probably should NOT have them.

If this is a public project, usually you have your cloned repository and you just make pull requests that the project admin checks. [More about pull request workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).